# Background image not repeating vertically

Tags: css, html, background-image, repeat

If you scroll to the bottom of this page - http://dev.socialadr.com/get/begin06 - you'll see that the white background w/ drop shadow stops near the end.

This is the image file that I want to repeat vertically:
http://dev.socialadr.com/mod/theme_simplebluewhite/graphics/theme_contentback.gif

The CSS file being used is:
http://dev.socialadr.com/_css/css.php

And I believe it's this #page_wrapper id that needs to be modified:

```
#page_wrapper {
    width:1014px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: url(http://dev.socialadr.com/mod/theme_simplebluewhite/graphics/theme_contentback.gif) repeat-y center top;
    height:100%;
}
```

I've tried tons of different things, read a bunch of other StackOverflow posts about similar issues but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Kane

Comment: What happens if you use a separate background-repeat property?

Comment: @bricker - Just tried it, doesn't seem to help. :(

Comment: I think it's the missing quotes around the URL. See my answer below. Without the quotes, the syntax is messed up and it's not recognizing anything after the URL until the end brace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try placing quotes around the URL:

```
background: url('http://dev.socialadr.com/mod/theme_simplebluewhite/graphics/theme_contentback.gif') repeat-y center top;
```

Comment: The page is referencing http://socialadr.com/_css/css.php, but you are editing http://dev.socialadr.com/_css/css.php. When I visit the first link, none of your changes are there and in fact it says "no-repeat".

Answer (score 3):

Your live CSS does not include the repeat-y property given in your pasted code.

Additionally, your image file is very large. Since the image is meant to be tiled, the image height should be the height of one tiling.

You should also break the image up into two pieces and set them as backgrounds on two different elements. Tiling the current image will include the top part of the box with the corners, which is not what you want. Set the corners-only image as the background on one element, then the tile image on another element with repeat-y.

Comment: Ahh good point, I had to clear the cache.  Now http://dev.socialadr.com/_css/css.php shows the updated #page_wrapper.

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion about breaking up the images is a bit beyond my skill set ;)

Comment: Yeah I've gotta figure out a way to break up that image into 2 pieces, you are correct that tiling looks silly :)

Comment: How can I mark multiple answers as "correct"?  You guys have both given me good advice.